# Location.subscribe() is leaking

Tags: angular

I use Location.subscribe() to detect "back" button.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/Location-class.html

```
export class PathLocationComponent {
  location: Location;
  constructor(location: Location) { 
     location.subscribe(val => console.log(val))//output popstate
  }
}
```

However, The number of logs increases when I repeat pushing "back"&"forward" button.
I think Locaion.subscribe() is leaking.
but I don't know how to release it because Location class doesn't have unsubscribe().

How to release Location.subscribe() or prevent leak?

---

I thought of using PlatformLocation.onPopState().
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/PlatformLocation-class.html

But,documentation says below

```
This class should not be used directly by an application developer. Instead, use Location.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can try this:

```
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';

export class PathLocationComponent implements OnDestroy {
location: Location;
private subscription: Subscription;

      constructor(location: Location) {
        this.subscription = location.subscribe(val => console.log(val))//output popstate
      }

     ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
     }
}
```

Comment: Thx!! But location.subscribe() return Object type.So error occur due to can't assign Object to Subscription.So I add "<Subscription>" in your code line8.